# Amazon Elastic BeanStalk, WAR Files, Hot Reloading

Tags: clojure, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I love the simplicity of Amazon Elastic Beanstalk.

However it seems rather difficult to hot-reload code. In particular, in reading about the [WAR file format (Sun)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_file_format_%28Sun%29), it states:

> One disadvantage of web deployment using WAR files in very dynamic
>   environments is that minor changes cannot be made during runtime. Any
>   change whatsoever requires regenerating and redeploying the entire WAR
>   file.

This is bad. I like to program in Clojure, which involves lots of testing / code reloading.

My question: what is the right way to to hot code reloading in Amazon Elastic Beanstalk?

Thanks!

Comment: @Steffen: the "> " is nice -- thanks. Initially, I wanted to indent it with "    " but then code don't line wrap, so I left it as plain text.

Answer (score 3):

Do your development on a local instance of Tomcat, an IDE like IntelliJ will automatically update your changes. Once you have reached a reasonable milestone, e.g. completed a story, then redeploy your war.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up giving the Amazon Elastic Beanstalk route, and just ended up setting EC2 instances.

Answer (score 0):

The tomcat installation on the ami's created via elastic beanstalk have hot reload turned off. @Rob's answer would be the way to go. I'm not sure why you'd want to do it any other way, to be honest.